# How to add a libpcre3-dev to docker image python3.8-slim when there is no installation candidate

Tags: python-3.x, docker, uwsgi, pcre

I'm using the Python3.8-slim image for a djangoapp that run on uwsgi, but uwsgi needs `libpcre3-dev` to build with pcre support.

When I add `RUN apt-get install -y libpcre3 libpcre3-dev`

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

...

# Configure apt
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils 2>&1

...

RUN apt-get install -y libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
RUN pip install uwsgi  # hopefully uwsgi should built with PCRE support now?
```

to my dockerfile, I get

`E: Package 'libpcre3-dev' has no installation candidate`

How can I install it?

Edit:  Here's the full Dockerfile: 
https://github.com/timberline-secondary/hackerspace/blob/f36cafd4c7d97eb989c37bbc9dfdc9c8ddf126c5/Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this message without apt-get update. Try below code.

```
RUN apt-get update &&\
 apt-get install -y libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```

Comment: Sorry, I am running update earlier in my Dockerfile.  Question edited. Thanks.

Comment: your docker file works fine with "apt-get install -y libpcre3 libpcre3-dev". Did you by any chance add "apt-get install -y libpcre3 libpcre3-dev" after "apt-get autoremove " ?

Comment: Thanks, but this installs it AFTER uwsgi, which I think means uwsgi is built without pcre support, whiih was the purpose of installing these libraries in the first place, per the questions.  When I move that line BEFORE pip install uwsgi, I get the error back again?!

Comment: I moved the line before pip install uwsgi . still builds fine. https://pastebin.com/duZLjuB9

Comment: I don't know what sort of dumb mistake I was making, but it's building now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line by

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```

Comment: Sorry, I am running update earlier in my Dockerfile.  Question edited. Thanks.

Comment: It's there in the link (less `apt-get install -y libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` which breaks it)